# The Buffers Puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The puzzle is called buffers. It is part of a company-made puzzle set at my office. It provides this image and the below sets of numbers/coordinates/something. I solved this once before a few years ago and now I can't for the life of me remember how. Answer is likely a single word or short set of words.

[image]

{x: 15, y: 13}, {x: 25, y:  0}, {x: 11, y:  5},
{x: 20, y:  0}, {x:  0, y: 12}, {x: 22, y:  0},
{x: 32, y:  3}, {x: 19, y: 14}, {x:  0, y:  4},
{x: 21, y: 12}, {x: 32, y:  0}, {x: 10, y:  0},
{x: 27, y: 14}, {x:  3, y: 15}, {x: 23, y: 14}

{a: 12, b:  5, c: 3}, {a:  8, b: 15, c: 10},
{a: 11, b:  2, c: 7}, {a:  3, b: 12, c:  9},
{a:  4, b: 10, c: 6}, {a:  3, b:  5, c: 14},
{a:  4, b: 12, c: 1}, {a: 15, b: 13, c:  2},
{a: 1, b: 5, c: 14}

Comment: Are you sure that image is complete? It's cut-off, so if we actually have to use coordinates that's a problem.

Comment: Yes, that's the image. I think its for illustration and not supposed to be used directly, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

I would never post this partial of an answer to a puzzle that you created, but since it is one created by another and one that you have solved before, maybe the below, if it is on the right track, will jog your memory and lead you back to the answer, or make you think of something that will do so.

I picked a point on a grid (marked red below) and marked the x,y coordinates in order as offsets of the red point that I picked.

I am using no spoilers because of the nature of this puzzle, and of this answer in particular.

I then used the second set of a,b,c data as lines drawn from a to b to c, and I got this:

[image]

I hope that helps, or at the very least is an example of what NOT to do.

Comment: Another thought I had was to separate each V-shape and fit them together in some way to make a word (or even a picture)?

Comment: This is cool. I don't see the answer here, but I like it! For some reason I think it has to do with Hex colors. The a,b,cs are all hex digits (0-15) and abc in hex is a color. And then the image is about color gradients. But I can't remember how it fits with the x,y stuff